# Start Google Assistant Voice interaction

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I've seen the Voice Actions API and it describes how you can create your own voice interactions that can be started by Google Assistant using keywords. This enables the user to say Ok, Google and then your keywords.  Google Assistant then forwards the interaction to your android app's activity.

I'd like to go the other direction.  I want to use a built-in interaction that Google Assistant already handles, but I'd like to begin the interaction from inside my app (meaning I want to pass some data to Google Assistant, or at least launch it with it listening).  Does anyone know if that is possible?  Each time my app detects a certain trigger, I'd like to prompt Google Assistant to begin a specific interaction with the user without them first having to say "Ok, Google".

I could do something similar by beginning my own interaction using text to speech and the speech recognizer service, but the voice sounds and work flow are so much cleaner in Google Assistant so why re-invent the wheel.

Alternatively, if there was a way to use the same voice and voice recognition used by Google Assistant I could work with that.

Any ideas?

Comment: This shortcut tutorial by Ido Green is helpful https://greenido.wordpress.com/2017/12/14/how-to-create-a-shortcuts-in-google-assistant/. For instance I created a shortcut for my own app that instead of having to say 'Ok Google talk to Chat Bot Chibi' I made a 'Chat Bot Chibi' trigger that I open with no problems by saying it on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked your question, Google has launched a developer preview of the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/) that sounds like it does what you want (or can). Although intended for embedded devices, it will let your users open a voice channel to the Assistant without having to say "OK Google" and get a voice response back.

There are some issues still with triggering something inside your app itself, but it is possible now and expected to improve over time. Currently you'd have to issue the command to your app out of channel - so either by having your server-side Action send your app a GCM message or by taking other actions that your app could pick up.